# Errors in running from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using OMNet++ 6 pre11 with INET 4.3.2 and it is working fine in IDE environment.

But, when I am trying to run INET showcase examples ( wireless/sensornetwork/omnetpp.ini) from the ubuntu terminal, I am getting the following error:

Command

```
opp_run -m -u Cmdenv -n ../../../src:../..:../../../tutorials:../../../showcases -l ../../../src/INET  omnetpp.ini  -c BMac
```

**Error**

```
<!> Error: More than one package.ned file for package 'inet.showcases': '/home/fa/Downloads/inet-4.3.2-src/inet4.3/showcases/package.ned' and '/home/fa/Downloads/inet-4.3.2-src/inet4.3/showcases/package.ned'
```

Would anyone please suggest the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in 6.0 preview 11 and 12, caused by the fact that the same directory is added multiple times in the NED path. My guess is that `../..` and `../../../showcases` is the same directory. I'm not sure where that `../..` is coming from, but try to get rid of it.

As a side note, this issue was fixed in 6.0pre13 version.